# Fixed length array vs fields

Tags: java, arrays, performance, field

What is faster?
I want to write an API for processing and calculating with vectors and matrices.
A "Matrix4f" needs 4*4 float values.
Should i write this as 16 fields or a two-dimensional array?
But if i use fields, inheritance is impossible.

Comment: What is faster? It depends. Measure, don't guess.

Comment: Arrays have O(1) lookup time, it shouldn't differ a lot. Would you really want to maintain 16 separate fields?

Comment: If its a lot faster, then yes, i want to maintain that.

Comment: No it wont be a lot faster. But always measure for your own sanity.

Comment: Never optimize prematurely. Write your code first in way it can be maintained easily. If you want to create code to handle matrices and vectors then arrays should be your first choice.

Comment: maintainability -> matrix .. say you need to expand size some day then matrix easy to alter (most logic may involve loop & size can be fetched dynamicly)

Comment: The faster approach is the one that more suitably solves your problem.  There is an extra indirection and bounds check involved in array access (two of each for a 2-dim array), but those are cheap.  I'm guessing that declaring/using 16 fields will involve a lot of code duplication and will produce more than a few bugs before you're through.  Plus, there is no way (other than very inefficient "reflections" to address the individual fields in an array fashion when you need to (as you no doubt will).

Comment: @HotLicks +1, your comment is the the best answer, including all the answers :) Additionally, the bounds check will be compiled away whenever a constant is used to address an entry (equivalent to naming a field in the object-based solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question of maintainability than speed. The speed difference between your two alternatives will almost certainly not be noticeable. The array approach, however, makes more sense in terms of what you are trying to model, and it's simply easier to deal with (say, for instance, you want to create a 5x5 matrix instead, then your array code will be easily reusable whereas your code with 16 fields would require drastic modifications). In short, don't worry about speed when making this decision, worry instead about what makes more sense and what will be easier to manage down the line; then the choice should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is no complexity in accessing an array nor in accessing a variable, `O(1)` so to say.

This is not what you should consider in speed, but your actual algorithms and functions.